# Python : Add Logo on top in reportlab

Tags: python-2.7, reportlab

I am using `reportlab` in `python-2.7` for generating PDF. I am trying to add Logo on top-Left in PDF using this code.

```
Story = []
logo = "logo.png"
im = Image(logo, 1 * inch, 1 * inch)
t = Story.append(im)
```

But its not shows `logo.png` image into PDF .Can someone tell me Where am i making a mistake?

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Table, TableStyle, Image
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

document = []
doc = SimpleDocTemplate('example.pdf', pagesize=A4, rightMargin=72, leftMargin=72, topMargin=72)
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

Story = []
logo = "logo.png"
im = Image(logo, 1 * inch, 1 * inch)
t = Story.append(im)

definitions = []
i, a = 1, 65
table = []
for x in range(1, 10):
    line = []
    line.append(Paragraph(str(i), styles['BodyText']))
    line.append(Paragraph('Vocabulary', styles['BodyText']))
    line.append(Paragraph(chr(a), styles['BodyText']))
    line.append(Paragraph('Often a multi-line definition of the vocabulary. But then, sometimes something short and sweet.', styles['BodyText']))
    table.append(line)
    i += 1
    a += 1

t = Table(table, colWidths=(1*cm, 4*cm, 1*cm, None))
t.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('VALIGN', (1, 1), (-1, -1), 'TOP')
]))

document.append(t)
doc.build(document)
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Logo in the wrong place? Logo invisible? Did you see any error messages? Any exceptions? What happens when you step through your code in the debugger?

Comment: @Mawg Its not showing any error.But Its not showing `logo.png` image into PDF

Comment: What are you doing with `t` in `t = Story.append(im)`? It doesn't seem to be used and is then overwritten by `t = Table(table, colWidths=(1*cm, 4*cm, 1*cm, None))` - btw, get into the habit of using meaningful variables names. In 6 months time, you won't know what this does.

Comment: Perhaps you needed to `document.append(t)` after `t = Story.append(im)`?

Comment: @Mawg Thanks for help.But its not working.

Comment: I guess you are modifying  [this example](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/) ? If not, it might help me. From your code above, I do not see how you are writing `im` to `document`, which is what you build.

Comment: @Mawg I am really sorry.It's working.Thanks alot

Comment: How did you get it to work?

Comment: @Mawg I added this line `document.append(im)` and it's working.Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append your logo to  the `document` from which you will `build()`.

Add `document.append(im)` after `im = Image(logo, 1 * inch, 1 * inch)`.

There is a good tutorial [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/)

Comment: Please can you tell me how to set logo into Left align?

Comment: That's anew question, Martin. We like to keep it to one question and one answer, otherwise it gets messy. Post a new question, but you can link to this one if you want to. Be sure to post your code, though - and tell where the logo is appearing at the moment? RIght aligned, centre?

Comment: It really ***should*** be a new question, but [this example](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/55200/reportlab.platypus.Image) makes it look like you want to `im.hAlign = 'LEFT'`